# How can i access DataService's catalog dependencies?

Tags: here-olp

We just started experimenting with OLP and first this we are trying to do is have a catalog in DataServices. If my OLP catalog has dependencies (on sources catalogs) how can i see them? I doesn't look OLP CLI has the feature. At least "olp catalog show " doesn't show that information.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the dependencies in the catalog metadata. There are three different ways to do it.

1. The fastest is to use OLP CLI. There is a command [olp catalog dependency list](https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/open-location-platform-cli/user_guide/topics/data/catalog-commands.html#catalog-dependency-list). The command can show all dependencies and direct dependencies only.
2. If you want to get the information from Java or Scala code then you can use Data Client Library. [QueryApi.getVersion(version: Long)](https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/data-client-library/api_reference_scala/index.html#com.here.platform.data.client.javadsl.QueryApi)
3. If you want to use another programming language then please look at the REST endpoint, see [this page](https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/data-store/api-reference-metadata.html#operation%2FlistVersions).